# Replacing IOS keyboard with Date Picker by button

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uidatepicker

I need to replace an already opened keyboard with datepicker by clicking a button! Searching on internet I'm only finding how to use datepicker as input for a textfield. Is there another way? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should replace the keyboard with UIDatePicker:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[self.someTextField setInputView:datePicker];
```

Make sure you declare the UIDatePicker:

```
class UIDatePicker : UIControl
```

The documentation on more info about the UIDatePicker can be viewed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker).